# Unable to run cmdline to rename computer

Tags: batch-file

Can someone help me to advise where goes wrong that I cannot change my computername even I run the cmdline using administrator account. screenshot shows error 5. (I have tried using /noprofile and /profile instead of /env and I got the same error)

```
runas /env /user:admin01 "cmd /k wmic computersystem where caption='%computername%' rename 'DS-32-333-X'"
```

[image]

Comment: Why are you opening up another instance of cmd.exe? Why are you using runas? Why do none of your images show your attempt when 'Run ad administrator'?

Comment: Just put only this in your batch file: ```@%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe ComputerSystem Where "Name='%ComputerName%'" Rename "DS-32-333-X"```, then right click on the batch file, and select 'Run as administrator'. Or better yet, open cmd.exe by selecting the 'Run as administrator' option, then type the full or relative path, name and extension of your batch file.